# Wi-Fi Calling over Ethernet in Airplane Mode

Tags: iphone, ios, ethernet, wifi-calling, airplane-mode

Does WiFi-Calling over Ethernet (with a compatible Ethernet-Adapter) work on iPhones with airplane mode enabled and no WiFi connection? I am using iOS 14.

Comment: It should work.  Airplane mode only turns off wireless connections, not the lightning port, so as long as you have network connectivity, it should work fine.

Comment: So the apps itself are accepting the Ethernet as equal network connection to WiFi?

Comment: Apps create/access a network socket. The medium doesn’t matter, in fact most apps don’t know how things are connected physically just that there’s a connection

Comment: The same problem remains in IOS 15.2: FaceTime, iMessage, and Wifi Calling do not operate over the ethernet connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this should work, but it doesn't. If you enter airplane mode while connected to Ethernet and attempt a call, you will receive this message:

"No Network Connection. Connect to a Wi-Fi network or disable airplane mode to place a call."

If you're on Verizon, a usable workaround is to download the Verizon Message+ iOS app. You can enable Calling within the app and it works to make and receive calls on your normal number. Texting also works, but it's standard SMS (no iMessage). Caveats: The app is meant for handling calls from another device and will tell you calling won't work properly on your primary device. This is normally true, but those problems are nullified while in airplane mode. Additionally, it will complain that WiFi is turned off, but happily works anyway with Ethernet.

One more note: iMessage through the Apple Message app should function in theory, but it doesn't work quite right. I can sometimes receive iMessages there, but not send.

Comment: I made the same observation. But Verizon is only an option in the US, not anywhere else in the world.

Answer (score 0):

Was having similar trouble with iMessage and Facetime with an iPad using an Ethernet adapter.   Turned off Airplane Mode, manually turned off WiFi and Bluetooth, and Facetime and iMessage started to work normally.  Using iOS 15.3.  So instead of using Airplane Mode, which turns off a group of things, turn off what you need to manually.  Remove the SIM if you absolutely don't want your cell connection on.

Comment: Well, turning off Airplane mode while I want to use Airplane mode (to disable mobile network) does not only look like a contradiction, it actually is.

Comment: Why do you want to disable the mobile network?  If traveling internationally, I would just remove the SIM while traveling.

Comment: Airplane mode prevents the phone from connecting to or searching for mobile networks. There are environments where this is needed. When removing the SIM card, Wifi calling does not work anymore.